# Angular 5 httpClient - using PUT jsonplaceholder 404

Tags: javascript, angular, rest, put, angular-httpclient

I'm trying to test Angular 5 httpClient PUT with jsonplaceholder but it's giving me a 404.

Here is the code:

```
 putExample() {
    return this.httpClient.put<any>('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', { title: 'sometitle' });
  }
```

What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: `404` means `not found` - will say that the server does not know any `PUT` methods related to that endpoint

Answer (score 2):

JSONPlaceholder does not have a PUT method for http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/ hence the 404 Not Found.

http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/

If you check the documentation again you'll see that for PUT requests will work with http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/:id where id is a number.

Comment: just like i said in the comment

Comment: When I try: http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/id:1 ... eventhough data with id:1 exists I still get 404

Comment: Try jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1, sorry might not have been clear enough there.